# Rust 1.4.0 (or later) cargo/rustc crashes when run in an AppKit app using NSTask in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoa, rust, appkit, rust-cargo

Rust 1.4.0 installation with multirust runs fine on command line, but crashes with signal 11 if it was being executed by NSTask in Apple AppKit.

I wrote some test cases to reproduce them. Current state is;

- A command-line program with NSTask. This works fine.
- An AppKit app with NSTask. This always crashes.
- An AppKit app just only links to AppKit. No actuall AppKit code in app. Also crashes.
- AppKit app wrote in Objective-C. Also crashes.
- AppKit app that runs cargo with BSD level pty instead of NSTask. Works fine.

This issue equally occurs Rust installation by building from source using Homebrew.
This issue does not occur with Rust 1.2.0 cargo and rustc. They worked fine.
This DOES NOT occur if the app runs out of Xcode debugger. So main reason seems to be the Xcode debugging context. It seems it is setting something wrong...
Running the app with command-line LLDB DOES NOT cause the issue. Ah...

I am using Xcode 7.1.1.

Test code can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/eonil/Rust140InAppKitCrashTestCases

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

Before you launch `NSTask`, do this.

```
    var envs = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment;
    envs["DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = nil
    // print(NSProcessInfo.processInfo().environment["DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"])
    _remoteTask = NSTask()
    _remoteTask.environment = envs
```

#### Explanation

Sometimes Xcode overrides `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to a non-system directory (something like `"/Users/Eonil/Workshop/Temp/Xcode/Derivations/EditorOnly-hfhkxuguvplpqvdcinldyuivhucp/Build/Products/Debug:/usr/lib/system/introspection"`)

And this environment variable is inherited as is to the `NSTask` instance because `.environment` was not set and remained as `nil`.

The cleanest solution would be setting all needed environment variables carefully.

I couldn't find a switch to turn off this Xcode behaviour.